# how to get ubuntu classic back on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

there is a gnome classic i tried that but it's not the same. it's so ugly . 
And if we can't get back ubuntu classic then please tell me how to remove that ugly pannel in the left side . Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

On your login screen next to your password is something like a gearwheel. klick on it and you'll see all possibilities of login-"shells"

Comment: There's only ubuntu and ubuntu 2d . There's no ubuntu classic option .So what's next...? N yeah by the way..thanks for ur reply olpanis.